# How to Add Login to my iOS PDF reader App?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I'm trying to add a login to my existing app. My App has two Storyboards one for iPhone and another for iPad. I added a login view set to rootViewController but I can't seem to load my UITabBarController correctly.Normally a PDF should load. I add the login that then segs to the UITabBarController but nothing is loaded its just an empty storyboard. I'm not loading it(the tab bar and document) properly or something. I'm a noob any and all help appreciated.

App Delegate file:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) PDFDocumentStore *documentStore;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DocumentListViewController *documentsViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DocumentListViewController *recentViewController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL launchingWithURL;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self migrateIfNeeded];

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.documentStore = PDFDocumentStore.new;
    [self.documentStore.rootFolder load];


    UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
   tabBar.delegate = self;

   self.documentsViewController = (DocumentListViewController *)[tabBar.viewControllers[0] topViewController];
   FolderDocumentListViewModel *folderModel =
           [[FolderDocumentListViewModel alloc] initWithFolder:self.documentStore.rootFolder];
  self.documentsViewController.viewModel = folderModel;
   [self.documentsViewController view];

   self.recentViewController = (DocumentListViewController *)[tabBar.viewControllers[1] topViewController];
    RecentDocumentListViewModel *recentModel =
            [[RecentDocumentListViewModel alloc] initWithDocumentList:self.documentStore.documentList];
    self.recentViewController.viewModel = recentModel;

   NSString *pdf = @"2016 Product Handbook";
    NSString *toPath = [[[NSFileManager grt_documentsPath]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdf]
                        stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"pdf"];
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:toPath]];
    NSURL *URL = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    if (URL) {
      self.launchingWithURL = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UITabBarController` in your `AppDelegate.h' file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
-(void)userDidLoginSuccessfully;
```

And then declare a public function in `AppDelegate.h` file. (Lets say userDidLoginSuccessfully is my function in this case).
In Your `AppDelegate.m` file write this function.

```
-(void)userDidLoginSuccessfully{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init]
    self.tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTabBarController"];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.TabBarController];
}
```

Then in you LoginViewController where you check the success of login within if-else block just write these lines.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate userDidLoginSuccessfully];
```

Comment: My LoginViewController is in swift. How do I input that part with swift syntax? I get a syntax "expected" separator warnings

Comment: Your entire project is in Swift or just the LoginViewController is in swift?

Comment: Also if you notice that in mycode the tabbarcontroller includes documentviewers and other things. I want everything to load properly.

Comment: Just the Login is in swift, everything else is objective c

Comment: You have to load the PDF in one of the view Controllers that is attached with the UITabBarController. Create separate class for each viewControllers assigned to UITabbarControllers. Then write the code in viewDidLoad Method what ever you are loading in you pdf.

Comment: Then create a bridging header to connect that swift file with objective-c. Then just import bridging header file in AppDelegate.h file.
Just write this code where the success of login is checked.
var appDelegete = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
appDalegate. userDidLoginSuccessfully();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114797/discussion-between-syed-e-hussaini-and-newhistoricform).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load `UITabBarController` after success of login. Right?

Comment: Yes I do. But at the moment I can't get the uitabbar controller to load without being the rootViewController. Any suggestions?

Comment: When ever you want to move towards tabBarController from navigationController always make sure to set tabBarController as rootViewController in you appDelegate and logout method will be the vice versa. (just set the loginViewController as rootViewController for logout).